# How to use grep with o option and [ ]?

Tags: bash, grep, brackets

I am trying to figure how to use grep with -o and [ ] brackets.  So i have a line that says

```
 <START connection="IP" name="test" extraname="testa" 2" data1="1" IP="192.1.1.1"></START>
 <START connection="IP" name="1test2" extraname="testb" 2" data1="1" IP="192.1.1.2"></START>
```

I basically want `name="test 2"`

so i tried:

```
grep -o 'name="[*]"'
grep -o 'name="*"'
```

I mostly get `name=""`.  Also a link to a page that shows lots of examples would be great also.

Comment: Note that `grep` stands for `global regular expressions print`. `regular expressions` are different than `wildcards`. `name="*"` is wildcard syntax. Equivalent regex syntax is `name=".*"`. But for your requirement the correct syntax would be `name="[^"]"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably need

```
grep -o 'name="[^"]\+"' your_file
```

Output:

```
name="test"
name="testa"
name="1test2"
name="testb"
```

And this is equivalent:

```
grep -Eo 'name="[^"]+"' your_file
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  May I ask what the + or the \+ at the end means.  I tried looking for it, but didn't find a syntax answer.

Comment: `+` requires that the pattern before it would have at least one match and can also have more. * on the other hand doesn't require a match. It could have 0, 1 or more than 1 matches. If you also need to match empty values i.e. `name=""` you can use `*`. By the way the difference with `+` (no quoting with \\) from (`\+`) is that the former is a form of extended regex while the latter is for a normal form of regular expression. At least with grep/egrep the statement is true.

Comment: See the fundamental structure section in the new grep manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Fundamental-Structure